shortcut property using COMMENT field
In Windows 10 Pro 22H2, when I create a shortcut such as this:

it often changes (on its own) to this shortcut:

which is what I do NOT want to happen! As you can see, my first shortcut provides a COMMENT box which allows me to provide useful information for future reference, whereas the second shortcut does not.
What must I do to prevent Windows from changing the shortcut so it will retain my COMMENT box? Most of the time this does not happen but if I can do something to prevent this I'd like to know about it.
Thanks,
Dan

Windows wouldn't do this. Something else is at play here.

What is the source object for the shortcut?

Harry...The source is the 'exe' file shown in my first Property display.

DanielB...OK, like what?
